# ¿Cómo solucionar el error al compilar referencia a `omp_get_thread_num' sin definir?

Tags: c, linux

**Salida:**

```
nitnelav@Nitnelav-Aspire-E5-411:~/Paralela$ gcc rendimientoparalelo.c -o rendimientoparalelo
     /tmp/cc8z3Rs6.o: En la función `main':
   rendimientoparalelo.c:(.text+0x134): referencia a `omp_get_num_threads' sin definir
rendimientoparalelo.c:(.text+0x156): referencia a `omp_get_thread_num' sin definir

Collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Código:**

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getch(void)
{
struct termios oldattr, newattr;
int ch;
tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
newattr = oldattr;
newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
ch = getchar();
tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
return ch;
}

int main(){

clock_t tiempo_inicio, tiempo_final;
double segundos,factorial=1;
int num,tid=-1,nth;
    printf("Ingresa un numero: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

tiempo_inicio = clock();

#pragma omp parallel for private(tid,nth) num_threads(32)


for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
nth = omp_get_num_threads();
    if (i == 0) printf("\n Ejecución en paralelo con % d hilos\n",nth);
tid = omp_get_thread_num();
factorial*=(i+1);
printf("El ciclo %d lo realiza el hilo: %d\n",i,tid);

}

 tiempo_final = clock();
 segundos = (double)(tiempo_inicio - tiempo_final) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;   
 /*según que estes midiendo el tiempo en segundos es demasiado grande*/
 printf("El factorial es: ");
 printf("%f\n ",factorial);
 printf("\n El Tiempo de ejecucion es: %f s\n",(segundos)*-1); 
 getch();
 getch();


 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Podrias dar más información sobre la pregunta

Comment: como solucionar el error al compilar referencia a omp_get_num_threads' sin definir

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz te sugiero echar un vistazo a https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058/conoces-los-magic-links-para-los-comentarios-aprende-a-usarlos/1059.

Answer (score 1):

Te hace falta agregar la bandera de compilación "-fopenmp".
Entonces la linea de compilación completa sería la siguente: 
gcc -o rendimientoparalelo -fopenmp rendimientoparalelo.c